# Solve the integral $\int_1^3\!\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x-...}}}\,\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

As an extension to my discussion in one of the answers to [my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3771778/simplify-the-radical-sqrtx-sqrtx-sqrtx) on simplifying the integrand, I'd like to evaluate the following integral: $$\int_1^3\!\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x-...}}}\,\mathrm{d}x$$

The above radical, when solved, yields 4 possible solutions:$$1) y=\frac{1}{2}(-\sqrt{4x-3}-1)\\2)y=\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{4x-3}-1)\\3)y=\frac{1}{2}(1-\sqrt{4x+1})\\4)y=\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{4x+1}+1)$$

Definitely, only one of these solutions has to be considered as an integrand. Since the limits of integration are positive(and square roots are involved), I suspect that the integrand must be positive as a whole. Thus, solutions $(1$) and $(3)$ are ruled out. However, I cannot decide which expression amongst $(2)$ and $(4)$ is legitimate. It was brought to my attention that this involves the notion of convergence, a concept I'm not yet completely familiar with(I have a naive understanding of convergence in infinite geometric series). Thus, I'd like to know:

> **Which of the above 4 solutions to the radical is legitimate for solving this integral, and why?**

Comment: Your previous question considered $\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x+y}}$.  I would do so again with your candidates.  Choice 4, e.g., makes this expression nonreal in $[1,2)$

Comment: @BrianMoehring I see. I'll try plugging in the expression for $y$ in each case and see what works.

Comment: If taken as a recursive sequence, it seems to converge to the answer that has $y(1)=0$ which is solution $2$ just from plotting higher and higher iterations. However this convergence only seems valid for $x>\sqrt{2}$

Comment: @NinadMunshi Please extend this notion as an answer.

Comment: I can't flesh out the answer, but it seems clear that this integral cannot be well defined because the sequence of functions diverges for $x<1.311$ or at least does something weird. Maybe it goes to $0$ like a step function?

Comment: @NinadMunshi Does that mean this integral is not solvable?

Comment: @Manan naively the convergence of the sequence of functions must be considered first before we can figure that out. The work you have shows that *if* the sequence converges it must be one of those two options. And option $2$ is the correct answer for $x>1.5$ at the very least, but the sequence looks like it either diverges or converges to something completely different below that.

Comment: I suggest everyone to take a look at @heropup 's answer to my question on radicals(link in question).

Comment: @NinadMunshi How about splitting the integral for different limits? For example, if one of the solutions is convergent in $[1,2]$, it can be used to evaluate the integral within those limits, etc.

Comment: In principle that is what should be done. But you should graph it for yourself to see what the problem is (it doesn't converge to anything, let alone the solutions you have visually below that $x$) This could also be some numerical error and not something to do with the function, but I can't be so sure of that.

Comment: I found the problem. If we define the sequence $$f_n(x) = \sqrt{x-\sqrt{x+f_{n-1}(x)}}$$ with $f_0(x) = 0$ (which is the only subsequence such that $x=1$ is not complex valued) then values like $1.1$ immediately become imaginary after two iterations. The integral can be done, but this function would probably be very complicated to get an analytical form because it deviates eggregiously from the square root shape. As a practical matter, this integral probably cannot be done by hand, and definitely not as a real valued function at all, which means the original sequence was ill defined.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I guess that qualifies as a closing answer

Comment: As an addendum, the reason why this means the original integral is ill defined is because roots in complex analysis are multivalued. If it were possible to restrict our attention to "real" roots only, then there is natural notion of picking a root to not be multivalued. However, in this case this means there are many possible values we could assign to this integral, which is generally not acceptable in real analysis. If the integral were from $2$ to $3$, instead, then it would neatly converge to option $2$.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Should I extend this problem with a complex analysis tag then?

Comment: No, it's not worth it. But I appreciate you thinking about the quality of your post for future readers. I feel comfortable leaving my last comment as an answer.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Thank you; I'd like you to post your analysis of this problem as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the problem. If we define the sequence
$$f_n(x)=\sqrt{x−\sqrt{x+f_{n−1}(x)}}$$

with $f_0(x)=0$ (which is the only subsequence such that $x=1$ is not complex valued) then values like $1.1$ immediately become imaginary after two iterations. The integral can be done, but this function would probably be very complicated to get an analytical form because it deviates eggregiously from the square root shape. As a practical matter, this integral probably cannot be done by hand, and definitely not as a real valued function at all, which means the original sequence was ill defined.

If the integral were from $2$ to $3$, instead, then it would neatly converge to option $2$.

Comment: Right, good spot! Just to mention, I had asked OP to ask this question in follow up to my answer on his previous question. +1!