# How would I simplify this function $\rho(x)=x+\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x+\sqrt{\dots}}}}$

Tags: calculus, functions, radicals, nested-radicals

How do I simplify $\rho(x)$ into simple terms?
$$\rho(x)=x+\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x-\sqrt{\dots}}}}}}}}$$

where the subtracting and the adding follows the Thue–Morse sequence $$+,-,-,+,-,+,+,-,-,+,+,-,+,-,-,+,\dots$$

I tried doing it with $x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{\dots}}}}}}}}$ and  got a answer by myself and I did it with $x+\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x-\sqrt{\dots}}}}}}}}$ and found a post here [Simplify the radical $\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x-...}}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3771778/simplify-the-radical-sqrtx-sqrtx-sqrtx/3771820#3771820) and I understood how it worked I would like to know how to solve a problem like this? where the adding and the subtracting never repeats.

Comment: If the sequence of $\pm$ doesn't repeat is this even well-defined? Usually this notation is meaningless unless one can ascribe a recursive sequence to it. The problem is, the sequences are usually defined from the inside out, which means that the outer signs are determined later than the inner signs. So the $\dots$ may be not be well defined because they could refer to multiple objects.

That's not to say we couldn't define the sequence outside to in, but convergence is easily not monotone or stable in that direction if we pick our domain wrong.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I didn't think about that thanks for your input I've been working on this problem for weeks

Comment: @NinadMunshi I would have thought at least for $x$ large enough (perhaps $x \ge 2$?), and a well defined pattern of $+$s and $-$s, then this can be calculated to arbitrarily accurate approximation, indicating that it is well defined.  For example I suspect $\rho(2) \approx 3.133605743$ and $\rho(100)\approx 109.51512292$.  But I would be surprised if in a case like this there was a closed form for $\rho(x)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't call this an exact closed form, but a 'close' one indeed. I remember a result in the paper (Page $28$); ***[A chronology of continued square roots and other continued compositions](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.06139.pdf)*** by Dixon J. Jones; he refers another problem reffered in $1899$ by Karl Bochow (Problem 1740. *Zeitschrift f¨ur mathematischen und
naturwissenschaftlichen Unterricht*) Which asks the reader:

> Assuming $0<a<1/2$: $$2\sin(\pi
> a)=l_0\sqrt{2+l_{1}\sqrt{2+l_{2}\sqrt{2+l_{3}\sqrt{2+l_{4}\sqrt{...}}}}}$$ For $l_n$ being either $-1$ or $+1$. Then;
>
> $$a=\frac{l_{0}}{2^{2}}+\frac{l_{0}l_{1}}{2^{3}}+\frac{l_{0}l_{1}l_{2}}{2^{4}}+\frac{l_{0}l_{1}l_{2}l_{3}}{2^{5}}+...$$

In your posed problem, we have

$$\small{\begin{align}
ρ\left(x\right) & = x+\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+...}}}}}} \\
 & = x+\left(-1\right)^{0}\sqrt{x+\left(-1\right)^{1}\sqrt{x+\left(-1\right)^{1}\sqrt{x+\left(-1\right)^{0}\sqrt{x+\left(-1\right)^{1}\sqrt{x+\left(-1\right)^{0}\sqrt{x+...}}}}}} \\ 
 & = x+\left(-1\right)^{m_{0}}\sqrt{x+\left(-1\right)^{m_{1}}\sqrt{x+\left(-1\right)^{m_{2}}\sqrt{x+\left(-1\right)^{m_{2}}\sqrt{x+\left(-1\right)^{m_{3}}\sqrt{x+\left(-1\right)^{m_{4}}\sqrt{x+...}}}}}}
\end{align}}$$

Where $m_n$ is the n-th Thue-Morse element (having $m_0,m_1,m_2... = 0,1,1,0..$). Now applying the first result:

$$\small{\begin{align}
ρ\left(2\right) & = 2+\left(-1\right)^{m_{0}}\sqrt{2+\left(-1\right)^{m_{1}}\sqrt{2+\left(-\right)^{m_{2}}\sqrt{2+\left(-1\right)^{m_{2}}\sqrt{2+\left(-\right)^{m_{3}}\sqrt{2+\left(-1\right)^{m_{4}}\sqrt{2+...}}}}}} \\ 
 & = 2+2\sin\left\{\pi\left(\frac{\left(-1\right)^{m_{0}}}{2^{2}}+\frac{\left(-1\right)^{m_{0}+m_{1}}}{2^{3}}+\frac{\left(-1\right)^{m_{0}+m_{1}+m_{2}}}{2^{4}}+\frac{\left(-1\right)^{m_{0}+m_{1}+m_{2}+m_{3}}}{2^{5}}+...\right)\right\} \\
& = 2+2\sin\left\{\pi\left(\frac{\left(-1\right)^{Sm_{0}}}{2^{2}}+\frac{\left(-1\right)^{Sm_{1}}}{2^{3}}+\frac{\left(-1\right)^{Sm_{2}}}{2^{4}}+\frac{\left(-1\right)^{Sm_{3}}}{2^{5}}+...\right)\right\} \\
& = 2+2\sin\left\{\frac{\pi}{4}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{Sm_{n}}}{2^{n}}\right\}\tag{1}
\end{align}}$$

Where $Sm_n=\sum m_k=m_0+m_1+...+m_n$. $Sm_n$ is also called the partial sum of the Theu-Morse sequence (find the sequence of that [here](https://oeis.org/A115384)). Now I'm not sure whether that sum has a closed form or not. I've seen certain other infinite series using Thue-Morse that *has* closed forms. There's a similar series to the sum in $(1)$:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{m_{n}}}{2^{n}}=2\left(1-2\tau\right)$$

Where $\tau$ is called the *Thue-Morse constant*

EDIT: To compute the series in $(1)$, you can use the following asymptote

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{Sm_{n}}}{2^{n}}\sim\sum_{n=0}^{4x}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{Sm_{n}}}{2^{n}}-\frac{3}{5}2^{-4x}$$

Which stems from the result that:

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{Sm_n}{n}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Nice job on getting that representation! I managed to simplify $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{Sm_n}}{2^n}$ into $\frac{10}{3}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{b_n}}{2^n} - \frac{2}{5} = \frac{10}{3} \prod_{n \ge 0} \left(1 - \frac{1}{2^{2^n}}\right) - \frac{2}{5}$ where $b_n$ represents the number of $1$s in the binary expansion of $n$.